# Is there a sqlite entension for PHP in RedHat Enterprise Linux 5?

Tags: php, sqlite, rpm, rhel5

I'm trying to use some off-the-shelf PHP code in RHEL5 which requires the sqlite package (not the PDO one) but it appears this is not included in the base php5.1.6 rpm bundled with RHEL5. Unfortunately, due to circumstances beyond my control, I don't have access to the installation media or RHN access (don't ask).

There doesn't appear to be such a package in the CENTOS 5 distro either (and I've read that its not in the php-common rpm there either).

Any ideas of where I can get this (withuot compiling my own PHP from scratch?)

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffering the same problem.
As far as i see it there are 2 possibilities, one of which you as you described cant use.

1. get the source rpm, rebuild it with the --with-sqlite option set in the .spec file
2. get the latest php source code and compile it with the right options
3. edit the spec file with php package and rebuild an rpm from it

Its not pretty but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked RHN but can't find it either.

Maybe it's available in EPEL.
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: Sadly not in EPEL - but python and PERL sqlite extensions are :(